# Macbook Pro mid-2012 Disk Utility First Aid Results Interpretation Help

Tags: hard-drive, high-sierra, disk-utility

My MacBook pro mid-2012 has been acting a little odd lately (freezing, losing track of files). I've run first aid in disk utility multiple times, but always get the same notes which suggests it doesn't fix them (see below). I've booted into recovery and disk utility tells me the hard disk is ok and still shows these same results. Are these results anything I should be worried about? Thanks!

> Verifying storage system
>   Performing fsck_cs -n -x --lv --uuid 08DE86D5-A3DC-4538-9A11-42C8C06CC8FE
>   Checking volume
>   disk0s2: Scan for Volume Headers
>   disk0s2: Scan for Disk Labels
>   Logical Volume Group 08DE86D5-A3DC-4538-9A11-42C8C06CC8FE on 1 device
>   disk0s2: Scan for Metadata Volume
>   Logical Volume Group has a 24 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
>   Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
>   Load and verify Segment Headers
>   Load and verify Checkpoint Payload
>   Load and verify Transaction Segment
>   Incorporate 0 newer non-checkpoint transactions
>   Load and verify Virtual Address Table
>   Load and verify Segment Usage Table
>   Load and verify Metadata Superblock
>   Load and verify Logical Volumes B-Trees
>   Logical Volume Group contains 1 Logical Volume
>   Load and verify AAA6EF91-6B7D-4D6C-806C-B24B184671B9
>   Load and verify 0E445AF6-FF17-41CC-BB25-0BCA0B9662C5
>   Load and verify Freespace Summary
>   Load and verify Block Accounting
>   Load and verify Live Virtual Addresses
>   Newest transaction commit checkpoint is valid
>   Load and verify Segment Cleaning
>   The volume 08DE86D5-A3DC-4538-9A11-42C8C06CC8FE appears to be OK
>   Storage system check exit code is 0.
>   Verifying file system.
>   Volume could not be unmounted.
>   Using live mode.
>   Performing fsck_hfs -fn -l -x /dev/rdisk1
>   Performing live verification.
>   Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
>   Checking extents overflow file.
>   Checking catalog file.
>   Checking multi-linked files.
>   Checking catalog hierarchy.
>   Checking extended attributes file.
>   Checking volume bitmap.
>   Checking volume information.
>   The volume Macintosh SSD appears to be OK.
>   File system check exit code is 0.
>   Restoring the original state found as mounted.
>   Operation successful.

Comment: First Aid checks to see if your file system is good.  An "exit code" of "0" means everything is good from that perspective.  It doesn't check to see if your drive or related hardware is failing (like the SATA cable).  What problems are you having exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This output means that the filesystem check has not found any problems with the drive.

If you're worried about "Volume could not be unmounted", it just means that the file system is in use while you're checking it. It does not mean that anything is wrong with the drive or the file system.